# Back button changes to Root View Controller when screen rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Hey I have a UIWebView in a UIViewController. I am also using a UINavigation controller. When oriented portrait the back button on the navigation bar says Back but when I go to landscape it says Root View Controller. Any idea why this is happening and how I can change it? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
           style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
           target:nil
           action:nil] autorelease];
```

source : http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/12/how-to-change-text-on-back-button-in-uinavigationbar-uinavigationcontroller.html